# Can't get values from inputs added in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I present you my curious problem.
I'm coding a function that permits users to add more email with input field.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form method="post" action="../admin/A_Office/publish_newsletter">
  <div id="list" class="input_more_target">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control"  name="email[]" type="email" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add more" class="add_field_button btn btn-primary">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

This script adds/removes new input fields:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper         = $(".input_more_target");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 
    $(add_button).click(function(){ 
        $(wrapper).append('<label for="email">Email</label><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="email[]" required type="email" value=""></div><input type="button" class="remove_field btn btn-primary" value="Remove">')
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

My problem is :

- When I click on add button, fields are added. But when I submit form,
  I just get the value from the first input email and not from the
  added inputs. (I just get => Array ( [0] => test@test.fr ) )
- When I add directly the second input field under the first (without JS), I get data from both.

If you can enlight me about this, it would be great ! Thanks !

Comment: Where is your Ajax function?

Comment: Please post your Ajax function and add missing source code (form, send button...).

Comment: Hi, I removed ajax because i dont need it here, i add form and send button

Comment: Unrelated side note: `wrapper` and `add_button` are already jQuery objects so doing `$(add_button)` is equivalent to `$( $(".add_field_button") )`

Comment: It sounds like my inputs are not considered

Comment: I've got an hint : my inputs are not included in the form...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find it ;
The form was opened in an outer div so i didnt receive any data